# How can I force Rails to reload application.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I've made some change in application.js, but even after restarting rails, I still have the same error and the source code the error show is the old one, it's not been changed. How can I force Rails to reload application.js?

Comment: try `spring stop` and than run `rails s` again and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invalidate all assets you should change the following value

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

and then restart the server.